# Trying to take Values from two different text inputs and put them in the same list item

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take inputs from two separate fields and put them into the same line using JavaScript. So far I've been able to take the inputs but they end up on separate lines.

Here is my HTML --

```
   <input type="button" value="Add A Gear Item" class='btn' onclick="addGearItem()">                    </div>
                         </form>
                    </div>
                    <!---Gear List Card-->
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <h5 id='current-list'>Gear List</h5>
                        <hr>
                        <ul class='collection gear-list' id='gear-ul'>
                            <table>
                    <tr class="collection-item">
                        <td>
                           <li class="collection-item gear-item">
                            IEM Pack 1
                           </li>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <li class="collection-item item-cost">380</li>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="collection-item gear-item">
                        <td>
                           <li class="collection-item gear-item">
                            IEM Pack 2
                           </li>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <li class="collection-item item-cost">380</li>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="row center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Purchase Item" class='btn'>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my JS Function:

```
function addGearItem(){
    let setGearItem = document.getElementById('gear').value
    let setGearPrice = document.getElementById('cost').value
    const newGearItem = document.createElement('li')
    const newGearPrice = document.createElement('li')
    newGearPrice.className = "collection-item item-cost";
    newGearItem.className = "collection-item gear-item";
    newGearItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(setGearItem));
    newGearPrice.appendChild(document.createTextNode(setGearPrice));
    document.getElementById('gear-ul').append(newGearItem);
    document.getElementById('gear-ul').append(newGearPrice);
    document.getElementById('gear').value = '';
    document.getElementById('cost').value = '';

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You've got a lot of invalid HTML there... `ul` elements can only have `li` elements as children, not `table` elements. Likewise, `li` elements can only have `ul` or `ol` elements as parents, not `td` elements. Decide whether you want an unordered list or a table.

Comment: tr and td without a table?  li without a list?  That's not right :(  Q: Do you actually have any unique HTML elements with the ids "gear" or "cost" anywhere?  Probably not :(  SUGGESTIONS: 1) To "combine" two elements, simply concatenate them into a string: `var s = myGear + ": $' + gearCost;` 2) To read a value from a table, you'll want something like this: `document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].innerHTML;`  First, please fix your HTML :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a ul tag closed in your HTML file, that might be a problem.
Also if you are trying to add two input values into one li element, then why are you creating two separate li tags in your JS function?

Maybe try this:

```
function addGearItem(){
  let setGearItem = document.getElementById('gear').value
  let setGearPrice = document.getElementById('cost').value
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${setGearItem} ${setGearPrice}`));
  document.getElementById('gear-ul').append(li);
  document.getElementById('gear').value = '';
  document.getElementById('cost').value = '';
}
```

Comment: This one sort of works, but the formatting is off. Right direction though!

Comment: Check your html code, there might by some more errors.

Comment: Yup, this basically works. I'll fiddle with the HTML now. Thanks!